# Proper loop header to drop into a loop based on parameters entered into a function

Tags: python, function, loops, parameters, arguments

I am writing a python function that searches a file for classes that meet the requirements specified by the function's arguments and to put them into a list. I have found a somewhat convoluted way to generate the correct lists **if all arguments are given**, but I can't figure out how to make the function work properly if only a few of the arguments are entered. How would I create a loop header that will initialize if only X number of parameters are entered? Or, if this is a poor question, what alternatives are there? Thank you.

The function as it is currently written is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include the code.

Comment: Don’t provide the picture of the code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question